# cant get data and run if statement

Tags: jquery, forms, if-statement

ok im trying to run an if statement on an input value of a form, I want it that if a user enters on of these names, once the click submit the if statement to run and return a console msg. How can i do this?

```
var manager = 'manager';
var business = 'business';
var person = 'person';
var username = $('#uname').val();

$('submitMe').on('click', function(manager, business, person){
    if (username === manager){
    console.log('yup manager');
}else if (username === business){
    console.log('yup business');
}else if (username === person){
    console.log('yup Person');
};
})
```

Comment: what is the `$('submitMe')` ? Shouldn't it be `$('#submitMe')` ?

Comment: How does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to your form

```
<form id="form1">
  Enter name: <input id="uname" type="text" >
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in the head:

```
$(function() {
  $("#form1").on("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDeafult(); // stop submission
    var manager = 'manager';
    var business = 'business';
    var person = 'person';
    var username = $('#uname').val();

    if (username === manager)
    {
       console.log('yup manager');
    }
    else if (username === business)
    {
       console.log('yup business');
    }
    else if (username === person)
    {
       console.log('yup Person');
    };
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it:

1. I would use the `submit` event instead of the `click` event
2. I would use an array instead of several variables
3. If necessary, I would use `e.preventDefault()` so the form does not submit until I am ready to do so.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var users = ['manager','business','person'],
            username = $('#uname').val();
        if( users.indexOf( username ) !== -1 ) {
            console.log( 'yup ' + username );
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="myform">
  User Name:   <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname"/>
  Password:   <input type="password" name="password id="password"/>
  <input type="submit" id="submitMe" value="Submit Me"/>
</form>
```